# Import XML with &gt &lt symbols in the data - powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Here is an example of the input XML

```
<log>
 <entry>
    <log_time>20160525-00:00:03</log_time>
    <description><![CDATA[Completed password Authentication. User logged in]]></description>
    <service>SSH</service>
    <sessionid>32321231</sessionid>
    <type>1</type>
    <severity>1</severity>
    <user>theuser</user>
    <host>mybox.domain.local</host>
    <lstnconnaddr>172.16.1.10:22</lstnconnaddr>
    <cliconnaddr>111.11.111.111:59999</cliconnaddr>
    <sguid>6EC9F549-AFDF-4444-2222-1CB9A65A9A8F</sguid>
  </entry>
</log>
```

So i want to know about things that are not severity 0 at the moment:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path Log.xml
$XmlDocument.log.entry | where-object severity -ne '0'
```

The description field comes back as:

```
description  : description
```

This is because of the way the data is formatted in the input xml - this comes from IPSwitch so I can not do anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it's value is a CDATA-section. You need to access the property.

```
$xmldocument = [xml]@"
<log>
 <entry>
    <log_time>20160525-00:00:03</log_time>
    <description><![CDATA[Completed password Authentication. User logged in]]></description>
    <service>SSH</service>
    <sessionid>32321231</sessionid>
    <type>1</type>
    <severity>1</severity>
    <user>theuser</user>
    <host>mybox.domain.local</host>
    <lstnconnaddr>172.16.1.10:22</lstnconnaddr>
    <cliconnaddr>111.11.111.111:59999</cliconnaddr>
    <sguid>6EC9F549-AFDF-4444-2222-1CB9A65A9A8F</sguid>
  </entry>
</log>
"@

$XmlDocument.log.entry | where-object severity -ne '0' | ForEach-Object { $_.description.'#cdata-section' }

Completed password Authentication. User logged in
```

You can also use a calculated property to replace the original description value With the "extracted" cdata-value..

```
$XmlDocument.log.entry | where-object severity -ne '0' | Select-Object log_time, service, sessionid, type, severity, user, host, lstnconnaddr, cliconnaddr, sguid, @{n="Description";e={$_.description.'#cdata-section'}}

log_time     : 20160525-00:00:03
service      : SSH
sessionid    : 32321231
type         : 1
severity     : 1
user         : theuser
host         : mybox.domain.local
lstnconnaddr : 172.16.1.10:22
cliconnaddr  : 111.11.111.111:59999
sguid        : 6EC9F549-AFDF-4444-2222-1CB9A65A9A8F
Description  : Completed password Authentication. User logged in
```